# How can I change icons programmatically?

Tags: android

I will use two icons instead of toggle button. My purpose is that ;

```
 If abc () == true 
          display(icon1)
 else 
          display(icon2)
```

How can I change icons programmatically in activity screen ?

Comment: use : `btn.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon1);`

Comment: @RaghavSood Instead of using toggle button, I want to use led. IF something is true display led which is on, if not display led which is off. On and Off Led is 40x40 icon.

Answer (score 0):

```
 If abc () == true 
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon1);
 else 
    button.setBackgroundResource(R.drawable.icon2);
```

Comment: In which directory should I store the icons ?

Comment: explain your question please

Comment: I should load image to some place. This place should be where

Comment: Inside your res folder as a drawable

Answer (score 0):

If it is an ImageView, then

```
ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.icon);
img.setBackgroundDrawable(this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.icon));
```

Likewise the icons can be changed

Comment: In which directory should I store the icons ?

Comment: i suggest you should read some initiations of Android before start developping apps , the icons and png files should be stored in the `res/drawable/` folder